# How to use Trim to get the Middle word SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ok guys working on this task I used the following trim statement to populate different table an example is

```
select Distinct 
    rtrim(right(FilePath, charindex('\', reverse(FilePath)) - 1)) 
from 
    [test].[dbo].[FileMetadata]s
```

to pull the last string after the \ in my table now the string I need to pull is the ABC in this column `\\doc\dfs\SCPD\Metadata\MetaData_Creation_Process\Members\ABC\SELL`

How do I go about this?

Thanks for your help?..

---

@ sgeddes

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileMetadata]([FileID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FileName] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [FilePath] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [SourceName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [SenderName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [FileSize] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [FileAttributes] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [FileExists] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [TypeID] [int] NULL,
    [ReceivedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FileModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ContentID] [int] NULL,
    [TransMethodID] [int] NULL,
    [ReceiverName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [LastUpdateTime] [datetime] NULL,`

so I need to populate the SourceName from the FilePath, an example is 
\Doc\dfs\SCPD\Metadata\MetaData_Creation_Process\Members\Femi\SELL, the source name here is FEMI I structured the folder well, so the content before the last \ is always SourceName, I have solved it using the LTRIM but I like your Logic and will like to Populate the SourceName using your Logic. I hope this explains better?.

Thanks

Comment: Since you tagged that with `c#` too, I suggest you simply split it in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could introduce a split function, or use this trick I learned a while back with `CROSS APPLY` splitting the data into multiple fields based on a delimiter:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn,
  Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS filepart  
  FROM  
     (SELECT 
        CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(FilePath, '\', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
      FROM  FileMetadata
     ) AS A 
  CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT C.FilePart
FROM CTE C
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(rn) maxRn FROM CTE) C2 ON C.rn = C2.maxRn-1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0afc/1)

Basically, the CTE splits the data with the backslash as the delimiter, and then selects the next to last one using the Row_Number.

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle if you have more than a single row -- get's a little ugly though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36526/1

Comment: thanks for your help, it looks like it is working but trust I have never seen something like this in SQL, also what if i want to use it for mulple comuns like  `\\doc\dfs\SCPD\Metadata\MetaData_Creation_Process\Members\dsw\IVNX` alot of them, what do I do, also can you kindly describe the ('/M') e.t.c

Comment: @user2183502 -- np, glad it helped.  What do you mean with multiple columns?

Comment: @user2183502 -- did you see my updated fiddle from my comment -- it should allow you to use multiple rows.  In regards to what it's doing, basically it's replacing all backslashes with some arbitrary XML node (in this case <M>, but any xml node will work).  Then it uses CROSS APPLY with string.nodes to split those -- built in for XML parsing, but as you said, rarely used. Once the nodes are split, I use row_number to get a number associated with each node, and then max(row_number) - 1 to get the next to last node.  Hope this helps!

Comment: @ sgeddes, I did not see the updated fiddle, I just saw it now, It works like Magic.  Thanks.

Comment: This also work but your logic seems to be the best.    `SELECT LTRIM(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(FilePath,(LEN(FilePath )-PATINDEX('%\%', REVERSE(FilePath))))),

PATINDEX('%\%',REVERSE(LEFT(FilePath,(LEN(FilePath)-PATINDEX('%\%', REVERSE(FilePath)  ))))))))

AS COL2



from FileMetadata
`   becuase I still need a replace or delete statement to delet the last \ ..

Comment: @ sgeddes I am trying to use your technic, how do I insert it into a filemetadata table? I want to insert tthe result of your code into a column called SOURCENAME (VARCHAR) NULL. Thanks.

Comment: @ sgeddes Can I ask few question about your Logic?

Comment: @user2183502 -- sure thing, what's going on?  In regards to your comment yesterday, should be pretty easy to wrap that around an INSERT statement.

Comment: Yes from your own stand point, how can I insert the result of your logic to a table, now the table has a fileID, but I can get to use your logic to call out the fileID with the filePart.

Comment: Yea I see what you are saying. But still got few issues. Let me show you My table structure.

Comment: @ sgeddes, I have posted the whole question as an answer, I think it will explain better. Thanks.

Comment: @user2183502 -- sounds like you need an update statement -- update the sourcename field from the filepath field -- try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9734/1

Comment: Yes Yes it worked perfect, so is it possible I make this a UDF and use it everytime just incase I have to? and how do I go about that?